# Android release build failing after upgrading Gradle from 6.5 to 7.2

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my project by doing the following steps:

- Upgrading gradle from 6.5 to 7.2
- Upgrading Android gradle plugin from 4.1.3 to 7.1.2
- Upgrading kotlin from 1.5.21 to 1.7.0
- Upgrading compile sdk version and target sdk version from 31 to 33

I can run my project properly in debug mode, but when it comes to release mode i get got this issue:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: StackMapTable format error: bad offset for Uninitialized in method 'gsnppnniskywjoq.oyyyoo$ooooyo gsnppnniskywjoq.oyyyoo$ooooyo.$INIT(java.lang.Object[])'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:385)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:385)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:324)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:750)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:298)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.doBuildStages(VintageBuildModelController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$0(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withModelOrThrow$5(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withModel(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withModelOrThrow(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:83)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:91)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:154)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: StackMapTable format error: bad offset for Uninitialized in method 'gsnppnniskywjoq.oyyyoo$ooooyo gsnppnniskywjoq.oyyyoo$ooooyo.$INIT(java.lang.Object[])'
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:71)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:54)
```

Any help ?